# Maya Python/MEL script to replace/swap out material

Tags: python, maya, mel

I've search around the web for about 6 hours without luck on this issue.

In autodesk maya (2016) I want to swap out/replace materials from standard phong material named "dg_plastic" to another sort of material named "plastic".

- The standard phong material will have a pre-defined name, as in the example above.
- We have a library of ready made materials with pre-defined names to pick from.

Is there a way to write a script in Python or MEL to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to apply a new material to stuff that already has materials assigned in the scene?

Answer (score 1):

There is a old thread on [CreativeCrash](http://www.creativecrash.com/forums/mental-ray/topics/batch-converting-materials) that deals with this. The script that i presented there look as follows (see original thread for more info):

```
proc connectAndSet(string $original, string $target){
    $conn = `connectionInfo -sfd $original`;
    if ($conn != ""){
        connectAttr -force $conn $target;
    } else {
        connectAttr -force $original $target;
        disconnectAttr $original $target;
    }
}

proc convertPhongToMia(string $original){
    $target = `mrCreateCustomNode -asShader "" mia_material_x`;

    connectAndSet($original + ".color", $target + ".diffuse");
    // ... any other mapping you need comes here...
    // a bit weak test should work for simple materials,
    // not used in special context
    $sg = `connectionInfo -dfs ($target + ".message")`;
    $sgr = `match "[^.]*" ((string)$sg[0])`;
    $sg0 = `connectionInfo -dfs ($original + ".outColor")`;
    $sgr0=`match "[^.]*" ((string)$sg0[0])`;
    sets -e -forceElement $sgr `sets -q $sgr0`;
    delete $original;
    rename $sgr $sgr0;
    rename $target $original;
}

for ($item in `ls -et phong`)
    convertPhongToMia($item);
```

It should be possible for you to re purpose this for your needs.